# Swift: could not find an overload for conversion that accepts supplied argument

Tags: ios, swift

If I set the argument to nil, the error appears. The code like this:

```
func addChild(childToAdd: UIViewController, childToRemove: UIViewController) {
    if (childToRemove != nil) {
        childToRemove.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    var frame = childToAdd.view.frame as CGRect
    frame.size.width = view.frame.size.width;
    frame.size.height = view.frame.size.height;
    childToAdd.view.frame = frame
    view.addSubview(childToAdd.view)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addChild(firstViewController, childToRemove: nil) //could not find an overload for conversion that accepts supplied argument
}
```

As you can see, I should not put nil in there, but what should I put into. It's working in Objective-c.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `childToRemove` parameter is defined as a `UIViewController`, which is not an optional **so cannot be nil**

try :

```
func addChild(childToAdd: UIViewController, childToRemove: UIViewController?) {
```

to allow nil value for you second parameter, and don't forget you need to unwrap your optional before using it (using **if let** is a great way to do so) :

```
if let childController = childToRemove {
    childController.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

briefly, you second parameter should be optional, if you'd like to send `nil`:

```
func addChild(childToAdd: UIViewController, childToRemove: UIViewController?) {
    if childToRemove != nil {
        childToRemove!.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    // the rest is the same...

}
```